# Error installing the noobslab Dark Theme in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, themes, ppa, proxy

I wanna install the noobslab Dark Theme in Ubuntu 14.04. I'm following the steps defined in the site http://www.noobslab.com/2014/05/delorean-dark-theme-updated-install-in.html but when I try the first step

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
```

I get the following error

Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:noobslab/themes'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.

Can someone please guide me to install the theme?

I've been searching for an hour and I don't get any answer to this error.

I'm behind a proxy and I checked the /etc/apt/apt.conf and it seems to be OK. Here it's

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://192.168.200.17:808/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://192.168.200.17:808/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://192.168.200.17:808/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://192.168.200.17:808/";
```

I'm new in Linux and I don't have idea about what can be happening :(

Thanks.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/themes - check the technical details for adding the PPA. The repository address that you have is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the lines below to your systems software sources:

`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu trusty main`

`deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu trusty main`

source: https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/themes

Comment: where are these? I mean where do i open it?

Comment: @AndiHamolli Please see the link in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507802/error-installing-the-noobslab-dark-theme-in-ubuntu-14-04/507809?noredirect=1#comment685362_507802)